# How to add a new excel column between two columns in a existing worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics

I would like to add a column that already contains cells values between two columns (or at the end) of a worksheet of an existing workbook that I load.

So I have a function that sets that "column values" I need :

```
private static Workbook SetIndicatorsWorkbook()
        {
            var workbook = new Workbook(WorkbookFormat.Excel2007MacroEnabled);
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Unit & Integration Tests");

//Don't worry about team and jenkinsBuilTeams variables
        foreach (var team in jenkinsBuildTeams)
        {

            worksheet.Rows[posX].Cells[0].Value = lastnbUnitTests + lastnbIntegrationTests;
            posX += 1;
        }

        return workbook;
    }
```

And then in main function I want to add this column (which is `workbook.worksheets[0].Columns[0]` ) in a loaded workbook :

```
private static void Main()
            {
               //The workbook I need to update
                Workbook workbook = Workbook.Load("file.xlsx");
                Workbook temp = SetIndicatorsWorkbook();
                WorksheetColumn wc = temp.Worksheets[0].Columns[0];

                //The issue is that Worksheet's Columns collection has no "Insert" property

                workbook.Save("file.xlsx");         
            }
```

Comment: @noas I'm not using Excel Interop but Infragistics.Documents.Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Columns** collection of the **Worksheet** has an **Insert** method that will shift data/formatting just as would happen in Excel. This was added in the 2014 volume 2 version. You can read more about that in the [help topic](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/excelengine-inserting-and-deleting-cells#_Ref397611617) or the [api documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.documents.excel~infragistics.documents.excel.worksheetcolumncollection~insert). Note I've linked to the WPF version help but the Insert method is available in the other platforms as well.